# Access value nested beneath unknown Python JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to access the date value of some JSON in Python, but it is nested beneath an unknown value. How could I access the date without knowing UNKNOWN? Below is a sample of my JSON. Thanks.

```
{"UNKNOWN":
    {"date":"2013-11-16"}
 "UNKNOWN2":
    {"date":"2013-11-16"}}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your particular example is invalid JSON. It's missing a comma in between the "UNKNOWN" and "UNKNOWN2" elements.

Assuming you have valid JSON in your hand, and you don't know the keys ahead of time, you can access all the values with `dict.values()`. If you need the keys as well, you can use `dict.keys()` (or `dict.items()`, which gives you both keys and values.

```
>>> x = {"UNKNOWN":
...         {"date":"2013-11-16"},
...      "UNKNOWN2":
...         {"date":"2013-11-16"}}
>>> x.values()
[{'date': '2013-11-16'}, {'date': '2013-11-16'}]
>>>
>>> x.keys()
['UNKNOWN2', 'UNKNOWN']
>>>
>>> x.items()
[('UNKNOWN2', {'date': '2013-11-16'}), ('UNKNOWN', {'date': '2013-11-16'})]
>>>
>>> x.values()[0]["date"]
'2013-11-16'
```